# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named - Python

Tags: python, python-import, modulenotfounderror

Can someone please help with this error? I have tried all sort of ways to import a module in Python but not has worked so far. I have this directory structure below:

```
|__folder1:
|      |__folder1a
|          |___inner_file.py
|__outer_file.py
```

I want to import a Class from the `outer_file.py` into the `inner_file.py`. However, I have been getting the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named`.

I have tried all the options in this link on [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-import-module-outside-directory/). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

easy

```
import sys,os
BASE = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.insert(0, BASE)
```

[image]